# Random numbers generator using unique/specific number in android studio

Tags: java, android, random

I am able to create random numbers from 1-10 which are in a range using (max-min)+min formula.

This is the code which is used to make random numbers between 1-10.

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Random random = new Random (  );
                int val = random.nextInt (11-1)+1;
                textview_random_number.setText ( Integer.toString ( val ) );
```

And this is for the 10-99

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Random random_two_digits = new Random (  );
                int val_two_digits = random_two_digits.nextInt (100-10)+10;
                textView_two_digits.setText ( Integer.toString ( val_two_digits ) );
```

But i want to generate random numbers with specific number or unique number.

Below are the specific numbers.

128
137
146
236
245
290
380
470
489
560
678
579

129
138
147
156
237
246
345
390
480
570
679
589

120
139
148
157
238
247
256
346
490
580
670
689

130
149
158
167
239
248
257
347
356
590
680
789

140
159
168
230
249
258
267
348
357
456
690
780

123
150
169
178
240
259
268
349
358
457
367
790

124
160
179
250
269
278
340
359
368
458
467
890

125
134
170
189
260
279
350
369
378
459
567
468

126
135
180
234
270
289
360
379
450
469
478
568

### 127
136
145
190
235
280
370
479
460
569
389
578

100
119
155
227
335
344
399
588
669

200
110
228
255
336
499
660
688
778

300
166
229
337
355
445
599
779
788

400
112
220
266
338
446
455
699
770

500
113
122
177
339
366
447
799
889

600
114
277
330
448
466
556
880
899

700
115
133
188
223
377

Comment: Do you want to get random numbers among those numbers that you wrote in the question?

Comment: Yes i want random numbers from this number only

Comment: Create a `List<Integer>` which contains the numbers, and shuffle.  `next()` returns the next element of that list by keeping track of the current index.  When the index reaches the size of the list, then reset the index to 0, and shuffle the list again.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all those numbers in an array, and use the random function you already have to select a number in that array. This should work:

```
int[] array = new int[]{128, 137, 146, 236, 245, 290, 380, 470, 489, 560, 678, 579};
final int min = 0;
final int max = array.length - 1;
final int random = new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
int randomIntInArray = array[random];
```

Shorter version:

```
int[] array = new int[]{128, 137, 146, 236, 245, 290, 380, 470, 489, 560, 678, 579};
final int random = new Random().nextInt(array.length);
int randomIntInArray = array[random];
```

Note that `Random` shouldn't be used for anything critical as it isn't cryptographically secure. You may use `SecureRandom` for more unpredictable results. See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html).